# tmux shows configurations on start

Tags: tmux, vim-powerline

**TMUX shows configuration on start:**
[image]

```
set option: status-fg -> colour231
set option: status-bg -> colour234
set option: window-status-fg -> colour249
set option: window-status-activity-attr -> none
set option: window-status-bell-attr -> none
set option: window-status-activity-fg -> yellow
set option: window-status-bell-fg -> red
```

How to make tmux not to show it? Every time I open tmux I have to press any key for this text to disappear and to start using terminal. 
This is my tmux config file:

```
source ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf #powerline tmux plugin
run-shell "powerline-daemon -q"
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

---

**This problem appeared when I installed tmux-powerline plugin**

**~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf contents:**

```
    1 if-shell 'test -z "$POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND"' 'set-environment -g POWERLINE_CONFIG_    COMMAND powerline-config'
    2 
    3 # Don’t version-check for this core functionality -- anything too old to
    4 # support these options likely won’t work well with powerline
    5 set -g status on
    6 set -g status-utf8 on
    7 set -g status-interval 2
    8 set -g status-left-length 20
    9 set -g status-right '#(eval $POWERLINE_COMMAND tmux right -R pane_id=`tmux display -p "#D"`)'

   10 set -g status-right-length 150
   11 set -g window-status-format "#[fg=colour244,bg=colour234]  #I #[fg=colour240] #[def    ault]#W "
   12 set -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=colour234,bg=colour31]#[fg=colour117,bg=c    olour31] #I  #[fg=colour231,bold]#W #[fg=colour31,bg=colour234,nobold]"
   13 
   14 # Legacy status-left definition to be overwritten for tmux Versions 1.8+
   15 set -g status-left '#[fg=colour16,bg=colour254,bold] #S #[fg=colour254,bg=colour234,    nobold]#(eval $POWERLINE_COMMAND tmux left)'
   16 
   17 # Simplify tmux version checking by using multiple config files. Source these
   18 # config files based on the version in which tmux features were added and/or
   19 # deprecated. By splitting these configuration options into separate files,
   20 run-shell 'eval $POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND tmux source'
   21 # vim: ft=tmux
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I think you run tmux 1.8 , update to version 1.9a and that should be gone .(this work for me)

2) If you can't update try this:

These four commands make such screen appear(each one and it's alias)(last one use lower case p) :

```
new-session -P
new -P
---------
new-window -P
neww -P
---------
break-pane -P
breakp -P
---------
display-message -p
display -p
```

line 9 use `display -p`

```
set -g status-right '#(eval $POWERLINE_COMMAND tmux right -R pane_id=`tmux display -p "#D"`)'
```

try to delete

```
-R pane_id=`tmux display -p "#D"
```

kill tmux and start it again